# Why isn't react-native dimensions API returning correct screen-height for android device?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have been trying to implement Instagram like  Reels page for an app in react-native, but the dimesnion Api isn't returning correct values in android?

There is always an offset at the bottom while calculating height in android device.
To have a better understanding of problem, you can refer to this video.

Thank you/

https://youtube.com/shorts/KCVr2K9TS_o

Comment: 'screen' or 'window'?